# Why am I getting this error when testing on a IPAD?

Tags: ios

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x374ec8bf 0x362cb1e5 0x374ec7b9 0x374ec7db 0x31dade97 0x278f 0x2c2d 0x307877eb 0x307813bd 0x3074f921 0x3074f3bf 0x3074ed2d 0x36000e13 0x374c0553 0x374c04f5 0x374bf343 0x374424dd 0x374423a5 0x30780457 0x3077d743 0x2439 0x23d0)
>   terminate called throwing an exception

I just don't understand why it was working until 5 minutes ago testing it on the same thing and now it's not working anymore. What can I do to solve this problem? The application works fine on the simulator.

Comment: What's the value of the var you're passing? NULL on device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string `cString = null..`

Fill it.

Comment: You defined a variable which stays empty.
Check your vars, print them to see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the string? One of the more common reasons for "works on Simulator but not device" is that you are reading from a file and use the wrong case -- device has case-sensitive file systems, but Macs have case-insensitive (typically).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it didn't work on the device is because I modified the database and for some reason the one on the device was the wrong one which obviously was incompatible with the new code. After I deleted the application from the Ipod and then ran it again it worked just fine.

The reason why I had that specific error is because some variables that were holding database columns were empty.